# On DUPLICATE KEY, Conditional statement error ambiguous

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO tb1  (title,Family,Complexity) 
Select o.title,o.Family,o.Complexity from tb2 o
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
     title =  CASE WHEN title <> o.title THEN o.title ELSE title END,
      Family = CASE WHEN Family  <> o.Family  THEN o.Family  ELSE Family  END,
       Complexity = CASE WHEN Complexity <> o.Complexity THEN o.Complexity ELSE Complexity END ;
```

I am trying to update tb1 with the records in tb2, ONLY if the records do not match up, as I am using an after update trigger in another table.

However when trying to execute this, I get an error "Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous".

I have been unable to solve this. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Try with full table name

```
INSERT INTO tb1 (title,Family,Complexity) 
Select o.title,o.Family,o.Complexity from tb2 o
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
     tb1.title =  CASE WHEN tb1.title <> o.title THEN o.title ELSE tb1.title END,
      tb1.Family = CASE WHEN tb1.Family  <> o.Family  THEN o.Family  ELSE tb1.Family  END,
       tb1.Complexity = CASE WHEN tb1.Complexity <> o.Complexity THEN o.Complexity ELSE tb1.Complexity END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `title` field exists in multiple tables/references.

You should prefix your `title` with the table name or it's reference.